# Java sockets, not all data transmitting, doesn't get to Wireshark

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, wireshark

I have system where 100's of clients connect to a server, via sockets, that I control.

When sending messages 99% of the clients work fine.

However, I have an issue with 1 client.
Everything works fine, then suddenly I will only get communication from the client, and I cannot send anything. The client will then timeout, reconnect fine, and the process begins again 5-10 minutes later.

Looking on Wireshark, when this occurs, data from the client is received, and acks sent. However, anything I send down the socket doesn't make it to Wireshark.

The data is sent via nio sockets within java, where socketChannel.write returns a positive number, indicating that data is being sent.

Any ideas on where to start looking? It is almost like data is backing up somewhere on the server (possibly needs to be flushed somehow?), but I wouldn't even know where to begin looking.

Comment: Just an observation: when 99 clients are working fine and one has problems, I would look at the client. I think your remark about "backing up" sounds right; possibly, the client stopped acknowledging packets and your server is waiting to send more.

Comment: I was initially convinced it was the client, however, the fact that wireshark doesn't show the socket data made me look into the server.
The client does keep checking for data, and this always returns no data. (Still having one way comms provides a little debug info).

So if data didn't get acknowledged would this prevent future data from appearing on wireshark?

Comment: Without seeing everything, I'm not able to say anything definite. There could be other issues, depending on how "far" the client is from the server.

Comment: "...However, anything I send down the socket doesn't make it to Wireshark..." Then how do you know you "sent something down the socket"?

Comment: Hi James,

Java responds that is has been successfully sent.

Comment: OK, on further investigation, it looks like there is a lot of TCP retransmissions with quite high RTO values.
If my understanding is correct, this is probably preventing the next messages from being sent.

I am beginning to think it might be easier to switch to UDP instead of TCP.